# Rendering react-native components within native android view (UI component)

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native

In my react-native application, I currently have a native Android view (written in java) properly rendering. When I try to put one of my react-native javascript components within it, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.yardsale.AndroidNativeListViewManager 
cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupManager
```

Has anybody encountered this? And if so, any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are your com.yardsale.AndroidNativeListViewManager extending ViewGroupManager. For ViewGroup, you should extends ViewGroupManager instead of SimpleViewManager

[extends ViewGroupManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7YQ4.png)